# Disable css box on desktop view but enable on mobile view

Tags: css

I would like to add customized css to disable floating box on desktop view but enable on mobile view.
Heres the css :

```
.floating-box {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
 left: 50%;
 .transform(translateX(-50%));
.clearfix();
background-color: #000;
 border-radius: @globalBorderRadius @globalBorderRadius 0px 0px;
padding: 10px 10px 8px 10px;
z-index: 9999;
width: 1100px;
}
```

Whats css should I add to make it happen?

Comment: Are you familiar with media queries?

Comment: Try media queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css media queries, and set a max-width

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {

    .floating-box {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media queries. For width greater than 768px(standard desktop width size) set the visibility to hidden and display to none. And for mobile and tablet views write your css code in the normal format.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .floating-box {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
    /* your any other css styles */
  }
}
```